# UNC build path in Team build (TFS)

Tags: tfs, msbuild, path, tfsbuild, unc

I am pretty new to TFS so I have this problem when I want to set a destination directory to my build.

Every time I launch the build, it dramatically fails and says "couldn't find \xxxxxxx\yyyyy\zzzz".

I think that my UNC path is wrong.

Let's assume that my drop directory (destination directory) is "C:\Project\" and my computer name is "lemoos-PC", what would the equivalent of my path in UNC notation?

I've tried these :
`\\lemoos-PC\C\Project\`

`\\lemoos-PC\C:\Project\`

`\\lemoos-PC\Project\`

but they don't seem to work.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, you should be able to use the following as your UNC drop location:

```
\\lemoos-PC\C$\Project
```

`C$` is a special 'administrative' share that is normally already available on your machine. The `$` makes it a *hidden* share that prevents other people from browsing to `\\lemoos-PC` and seeing it listed. Other people can only access it if they both a) know the name of the share and b) have administrative access to the computer.

Answer (score 2):

The UNC path is really a path to a shared network folder and it would have the format

```
\\computername\sharename\directory\in\share
```

so it would depend on what the name of your network share is, not necessarily what your local path is. If you for example share your C:\Project folder as Project, the path would be

```
\\lemoos-PC\Project\
```

Comment: What is a 'share'? How to know it ? I am using TFS on my personal computer there is no such a thing such a share .

Comment: If you want to use UNC paths (although I'm not sure why TFS would require that, I'm no TFS expert), you need to create a network share to access it. How to create a network share would depend on which version of Windows you are running, but there is plenty of information on Google on that subject.