# TFS:Build Partially Succeeded with errors1.Website 696283980 Doesn't Exists on <serverNameHere>2.A valid UNC path was not specified for UNCPathToClean

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, asp.net-development-serv

I have my code changes in Developer Environment which is working fine but when I am trying to deploy the changes to Integration Environment using TFS, build deployment is getting partially completed.

Below are the two errors which are causing the deployment to be completed partially.

1. Website `<somesitenumber>` Doesn't Exists on `<servernameHere>`.
2. A valid UNC path was not specified for UNCPathToClean.

Comment: Which build are you using, the old XAML build or new vNext build？Could  you share the detail part log info of your partially succeeded build?

Comment: It's new build.

Comment: Hi   PatrickLu-MSFT, sorry for late response. regarding this .. seems like due to some reason TFS server was off and when the code build tried to deploy changes into work space in server, it could not identify server as it was off.

Answer (score 0):

For error1 suggest you manually remote to the target server and check if the website exists or not.

For error2  UNC path is a share folder, so that your team can access outputs such as those from builds. You can get more information about drop folder from [Set Up Drop Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb778394(v=vs.120).aspx).

It’s important that you use UNC path only for drop share location in TFS Builds. So you can take a folder from your local machine and then share it with “Build Services Account” with Read/Write permissions.

Then you can get to the local folder via UNC path as `\\[YourMachineName]\[ShareName]` and this is what you could use in your TFS Build Definition.

More details please take a look at this question: [UNC build path in Team build (TFS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955581/unc-build-path-in-team-build-tfs)